# Need Help with SP2010 calculated or scripted field based on multiple other colums of data

Tags: javascript, calculated-column

In a SP2010 environment, I have a couple challenges.  I have a list of records that I need to add a calculated field (we'll call this column "STATUS Ratio) for each persons record.  Each record has approximately 80 potential entries (columns of data) that can be toggled between 4 options (Yes/No/Partial/No Access).  The first entry of each persons record is the column called "ROLE" (there are approximately 10 different types of roles or positions that people in the company are assigned).

Here's the challenge... 
First, based on the "ROLE" selected, only certain columns (of the 80 possible columns) will be available and all remaining fields not applicable for that ROLE need to be non-editable or non-viewable.
Second, the "STATUS Ratio" field needs to calculate the ratio of completed fields for that person based on the role selected.

I really need help on this as quickly as possible to help build a jscript, HTML, or whatever would work on a SP 2010 page to achieve this task.

Thank you in advance for any help,

Comment: You won't get much help; your question is way too complex, lacks graphics (a picture says more than a thousand words. ) And "*as quickly as possible*" is likely to be read as "I can't do my job, so please you do it for me"

Comment: Are you are asking us to write a solution for you? I recommend you reconsider your architecture, get some work done, and come back with specific questions. Also, please acknowledge that you have read and recognize the limits of SharePoint lists and you intentionally want to build something outside of the recommendations.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments.  I understand this is a complex task, and yes I understand this can seem like what you said Danny.  I am a program manager by trade, but happen to be in a position to help develop SharePoint 2007, 2010, and 2013 client side environments. Although I know a bit of coding, this seems a bit out of my lane, this is why I was seeking some help from the community.  I have other feelers out though, but thus far nothing definitive.

Comment: I'm not relying on the field for the work, simply asking for some tips in the right direction.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest dev cycle time would be to keep 80 pieces of data in identical ways and write your interface to reuse the code as much as possible. Also, minimize the number of fields per query, and queries per view. You will note from the example that this format scales well.

The single field could be as easy as a hash where you use 2 bits for each item and use your web form to "and" the values out. You could do this in infopath with XSL, but you *may* eventually upgrade to a current system, so I would avoid that. If you create 80 columns in the list for your data you will have architectural limitations on being able to query and update them. Also, you will have a great deal of effort put into the user interface to keep it from becoming a monster.

The simplest form would be to encode your fields into binary and your 4 values would be available in bits, storing all your data in a 20 character string. an example: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305144

*Humor--*
The easiest for you to read and safest to transfer would be a 80 character string with a single letter for each possible value an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_code)  If you choose this route take care to make sure your editor is very [reliable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRISPR).